# Yet another mathematical vector class

Tags: c++, coordinate-system, linear-algebra

This is an implementation of a mathematical vector.
I am currently working on a linear algebra project and before proceeding further with other classes (matrix, polar_vector etc.) I would like to have some code review if someone's up for that.

Currently complex components are supported but not all operations are defined for them (yet), because I need to learn some new stuff before implementing them.
But anyway, what I'd like to be reviewed mostly:

- Design. I'm sure I have a lot to improve from this perspective. Tell me anything!
- Code review. Probably I could've have written some things better? I'm open to new ideas.

Here's the code.

````cpp
#ifndef MATH_VECTOR_MINILIBRARY
#define MATH_VECTOR_MINILIBRARY


#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <initializer_list> 
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>


// Todo: remove friend functions from vector and move them in namespace Math::

namespace Math {

    enum class Cos { ALPHA = 0, BETA, THETA };

    template<typename T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
    template<typename T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

    // only allows arithmetic types (chars excluded) and complex numbers. 
    // const types are unneccessary as they disallow most operations.
    template<typename T>
    concept underlying_vector_type =
        (is_complex<T>::value or std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
        and not std::is_same_v<T, char>
        and not std::is_const_v<T>;

    template<typename T>
    concept arithmetic_char_const_excluded =
        std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
        and not std::is_same_v<T, char>
        and not std::is_const_v<T>;

#define ASSERT_SIZE_MISMATCH(Size, Size2) assert((Size2 >= Size && "Size mismatch!"));

#define ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(Value) assert((Value != T{} && "Cannot perform division by zero!"));

#define STATICASSERT_COMPLEX_DIFFTYPES(Type1, Type2)\
if constexpr (is_complex<T>::value)\
static_assert(std::same_as<Type1, Type2>);\

    /*
        General vector expressed in cartesian coordinates - accepts the specified type and any size.
        Not all internal operations are yet defined for complex numbers.
        For a specialization of this vector representation with polar coordinates, see @...
    */

    template<underlying_vector_type T, std::size_t Size>
    class vector {

    private:
        template<underlying_vector_type T2, std::size_t Size2>
        friend class vector;

        T _vector[Size]{};

    public:
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer_type = T*;
        using reference_type = T&;
        using const_pointer_type = T* const;

        /*
        Constructors: default (1), same value for all elements (2), initialize internal vector through another container (3),
        initialize internal vector through an multiple values (4), fill the internal vector with random
        numbers (5), others = defaulted
        */

        constexpr vector() = default;

        constexpr explicit vector(value_type value) {
            std::fill(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector), value);
        }

        template<std::input_iterator InputIter>
        constexpr vector(InputIter first, InputIter last) {
            static_assert(std::convertible_to<value_type,
                typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type>,
                "The type of InputIter must be convertible to the type of Math::Vector");
            ASSERT_SIZE_MISMATCH(std::distance(first, last), Size);

            std::copy(first, last, std::begin(_vector));
        }

        /* [4]
        template<typename First, typename... Rest>
        requires (std::convertible_to<value_type, First>
        and std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<First, Rest>...>
        and sizeof...(Rest) + 1 <= Size)
        constexpr explicit vector(const First& first, const Rest... rest)
            : _vector{first, rest...} {}
        */

        /* Call such as Math::vector<int, 6> vec({3,4,5,2});
           This constructor was added instead of constructor [4] to avoid
           a call such as Math::vector<int, 2> vec(2, 3) to call constructor [4],
           and instead prefer the constructor initializing the vector through random numbers
           (by passing std::size_t lower, std::size_t higher).
        */
        template<std::size_t Sz, typename T2>
        constexpr explicit vector(const T2 (&arr)[Sz])
        requires (std::convertible_to<value_type, T2>)
            : vector(arr, std::make_index_sequence<Sz>{}) {}

    private:
        // Perhaps taking const T2(&arr)[Size] would make this slower in case Size is very big and the caller
        // only passes a small array? Take advantage of that and take a size that represents the actual size of the passed array
        // instead: needs further checks too see if this improves anything
        template <typename T2, std::size_t... Index>
        constexpr explicit vector(const T2(&arr)[sizeof...(Index)],
            std::index_sequence<Index...>)
            : _vector{ arr[Index]... } {}

    public:
        template<typename T2, std::size_t Size2>
        constexpr vector(const vector<T2, Size2>& other)
        requires (Size2 <= Size) {
            std::copy(std::begin(other._vector), std::end(other._vector),
                std::begin(_vector));
        }

        // Currently useless; keep for future changes of the allowed types.
        template<typename T2, size_type Size2>
        constexpr vector(vector<T2, Size2>&& other) /*noexcept (std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)*/
        requires (Size2 <= Size) {
            std::move(std::begin(other._vector), std::end(other._vector),
                std::begin(_vector));
        }

        constexpr explicit vector(size_type lower, size_type higher) {
            std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device{}());
            std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist(lower, higher);

            for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
                _vector[i] = dist(mt);
            }
        }

        // Initialize the complex vector with random initial real and imaginary values
        constexpr explicit vector(size_type lower, size_type higher)
        requires (is_complex<T>::value) {
            std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device{}());
            std::uniform_real_distribution<typename T::value_type> dist(lower, higher);

            for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i) {
                _vector[i] = { dist(mt), dist(mt) };
            }
        }

        constexpr vector(const vector& other) = default;
        constexpr vector(vector&& other) /*noexcept*/ = default;
        constexpr vector& operator=(vector&& other) /*noexcept*/ = default;
        constexpr vector& operator=(const vector& other) = default;


        template<typename Function>
        constexpr vector apply_foreach(const Function& function)
        noexcept(noexcept(function)) {

            for (size_type i{}; i < Size; ++i) {
                function(_vector[i]);
            }
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr const T& operator[] (size_type index) const noexcept {
            return _vector[index];
        }

        constexpr T& operator[] (size_type index) noexcept {
            return _vector[index];
        }

        constexpr T& get_x() const noexcept {
            return _vector[0];
        }

        constexpr T& get_y() const noexcept
        requires (Size >= 1) {
            return _vector[1];
        }

        constexpr T& get_z() const noexcept
        requires (Size >= 2) {
            return _vector[2];
        }

        constexpr T& get_w() const noexcept
        requires (Size >= 3) {
            return _vector[3];
        }

        // Addition operations
        template<typename T2>
        constexpr vector& operator+=(const vector<T2, Size>& rhs) {
            STATICASSERT_COMPLEX_DIFFTYPES(T, T2);

            for (size_type i = 0; const auto & element : rhs._vector) {
                _vector[i++] += element;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        constexpr vector& operator+=(T2 val) {
            std::for_each(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector),
                [val](T& current) {
                    current += val;
                });

            return *this;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator+(vector lhs, T2 val) {
            return lhs += val;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator+(T2 val, vector lhs) {
            return lhs += val;
        }

        template<typename T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator+(vector lhs, const vector<T2, Size>& rhs) {
            return lhs += rhs;
        }

    public:
        constexpr vector operator-()
        requires (not std::is_unsigned<T>::value) {
            vector temp = *this;
            for (auto& current : temp) {
                current = -current;
            }
            return temp;
        }


        // Substraction operations
    private:
        template<typename T2>
        constexpr vector& substract(const vector<T2, Size>& rhs) {
            STATICASSERT_COMPLEX_DIFFTYPES(T, T2);

            for (size_type i = 0; const auto & element : rhs._vector) {
                _vector[i++] -= element;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        constexpr vector& substract(T2 val) {
            std::for_each(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector),
                [val](auto& current) {
                    current -= val;
                });

            return *this;
        }

    public:
        template<typename T2>
        constexpr vector& operator-=(const vector<T2, Size>& rhs) {
            return substract(rhs);
        }

        template<typename T2>
        [[deprecated("substracting vector of type unsigned might cause issues!")]]
        constexpr vector& operator-=(const vector<T2, Size>& rhs)
        requires std::is_unsigned<T>::value {
            return substract(rhs);
        }

        template<typename T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator-(vector lhs, const vector<T2, Size>& rhs) {
            return lhs -= rhs;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        constexpr vector& operator-=(T2 val) {
            return substract(val);
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        [[deprecated("substracting from an unsigned vector might cause issues!")]]
        constexpr vector& operator-=(T2 val)
        requires std::is_unsigned<T>::value{
            return substract(val);
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator-(vector lhs, T2 val) {
            return lhs -= val;
        }
    
    private:
        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        constexpr vector& lambda_multiplicator(T2 lambda) {
            std::for_each(begin(), end(), [lambda](auto& current) { 
                current *= lambda; 
                });

            return *this;
        }

    public:
        // Multiplication with a Lambda - Scalar multiplication
        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        constexpr vector& operator*=(T2 lambda) {
            return lambda_multiplicator(lambda);
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        [[deprecated("multiplying vector of type unsigned might cause issues!")]]
        constexpr vector& operator*=(T2 lambda)
        requires std::is_unsigned<T>::value{
            return lambda_multiplicator(lambda);
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator*(vector lhs, T2 lambda) {
            return lhs *= lambda;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator*(T2 lambda, vector lhs) {
            return lhs *= lambda;
        }


        // Cross product
    private:
        template<typename T2>
        constexpr vector& cross_product_internal(const vector<T2, Size>& rhs)
        requires (Size == 3 
        and std::is_convertible<T2, value_type>::value) {
            vector temp{ *this };

            if constexpr (is_complex<T>::value) {
                STATICASSERT_COMPLEX_DIFFTYPES(T, T2);

                // The cross product for complex vectors has the same formulas as a cross product in R3, with the only
                // difference being that the final step is taking the complex conjugates of the results.
                _vector[0] = std::conj((temp[1] * rhs[2] - temp[2] * rhs[1]));
                _vector[1] = std::conj((temp[2] * rhs[0] - temp[0] * rhs[2]));
                _vector[2] = std::conj((temp[0] * rhs[1] - temp[1] * rhs[0]));
                return *this;
            }

            _vector[0] = temp[1] * rhs[2] - temp[2] * rhs[1];
            _vector[1] = temp[2] * rhs[0] - temp[0] * rhs[2];
            _vector[2] = temp[0] * rhs[1] - temp[1] * rhs[0];
            return *this;
        }

    public:
        template<typename T2>
        constexpr vector& cross_product(const vector<T2, Size>& rhs) {
            return cross_product_internal(rhs);
        }


        template<typename T2>
        [[deprecated("Multiplication on two vectors of type unsigned might cause issues!")]]
        constexpr vector& cross_product(const vector<T2, Size>& rhs)
        requires std::is_unsigned<T>::value {
            return cross_product_interna(rhs);
        }

        // Not in-place
        template<typename T2>
        friend constexpr vector cross_product(vector lhs, const vector<T2, Size>& rhs) {
            return lhs.cross_product_internal(rhs);
        }

        // Division with a constant/lambda - for precision and correctness, use multiplication instead
        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        constexpr vector& operator/=(T2 lambda) {
            ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(lambda);

            std::for_each(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector),
                [lambda](auto& current) {
                    current /= lambda;
                });

            return *this;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        friend constexpr vector operator/(vector lhs, T2 lambda) {
            return lhs /= lambda;
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T2>
        constexpr vector& operator%=(T2 lambda)
        requires (std::is_integral_v<T> 
        and std::is_integral_v<T2>
        and !is_complex<T>) {
            ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(lambda);

            std::for_each(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector),
                [lambda](auto& current) {
                    current %= lambda;
                });

            return *this;
        }


        constexpr void reset() noexcept {
            std::fill(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector), T{});
        }

        template<underlying_vector_type T1>
        constexpr auto inner_product(const vector<T1, Size>& other) const {
            return std::inner_product(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector),
                std::begin(other._vector), T{});
        }

        friend constexpr auto scalar_triple_product(const vector& first,
            const vector& other2, const vector& other3)
        requires (Size == 3 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            vector temp{ first };
            return other3.inner_product(temp.cross_product(other2));
        }

        // Not in place
        friend constexpr vector vector_triple_product(const vector& first, const vector& other2,
            const vector& other3)
        requires (Size == 3 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            vector temp{ first };
            vector temp3{ other3 };
            return temp3.cross_product(temp.cross_product(other2));
        }

        friend constexpr bool are_coplanar(const vector& first, const vector& other2,
            const vector& other3)
        requires (Size == 3 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            auto result = scalar_triple_product(first, other2, other3);
            return result >= 0 && result <= 1E-6;
        }


        // Calculates projection of other to this, then stores the result in this (inplace)
        template<typename T2>
        constexpr vector& vector_projection_from(const vector<T2, Size>& other) {
            T denominator = inner_product(*this);
            // a null vector results in a scalar product of 0, thus a denominator of 0
            // todo: decide whether this is the appropriate way to proceed, or whether another result can be given (eg. using limits)
            ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(denominator);
            *this *= (inner_product(other) / denominator);

            return *this;
        }

        // Return direction of a 2D vector. The vector components must be cartesian coordinates. x will return (angle)x, 
        // y returns (angle)y. 
        constexpr double direction_radiants_y() const 
        requires (Size == 2 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            return std::atan2(_vector[0], _vector[1]); // (x / y)
        }

        constexpr double direction_radiants_x() const 
        requires (Size == 2 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            return std::atan2(_vector[1], _vector[0]); // (y / x)
        }

        constexpr double direction_degrees_y() const {
            return direction_radiants_y() * 180.0 / 3.141592653589793238463;
        }

        constexpr double direction_degrees_x() const {
            return direction_radiants_x() * 180.0 / 3.141592653589793238463;
        }


        // Direction cosines of 3D vectors.
        constexpr double direction_cosine(Cos type) const 
        requires (Size == 3 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            double denominator = magnitude();
            ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(denominator);

            return static_cast<double>(_vector[static_cast<int>(type)] / denominator);
        }

        constexpr double direction_angle(Cos type) const 
        requires (Size == 2 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            return std::acos(direction_cosine(type));   
        }

        constexpr vector& normalize() {
            double denominator = magnitude();
            ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(denominator);
            *this *= (1 / denominator);
            return *this;
        }

        // Return || magnitude || of this vector
        constexpr double magnitude() const {
            double sum = std::accumulate(begin(), end(), T{},
                [](auto internal_sum, const auto& element) { 
                    return internal_sum + std::pow(element, 2); 
                });

            return std::sqrt(sum);
        }

        // Computes the norm for a complex vector
        constexpr double magnitude() const
        requires (is_complex<T>::value) {
            // The norm of a complex vector has a different definition than that of a vector with R components.
            double sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector), 0,
                [](auto sum, const auto& element) {
                    return sum + std::pow(std::abs(element.real()), 2)
                        + std::pow(std::abs(element.imag()), 2);
                });

            return std::sqrt(sum);
        }

        // Vector Parallelism Condition
        // 3 dimensions case: checks whether the cross product is near 0
        template<typename T2>
        friend constexpr bool are_parallel(const vector& first, const vector<T2, Size>& other)
        requires (Size == 3 
        and not is_complex<T>::value 
        and not is_complex<T2>::value)
        {
            vector temp_cross = first;
            vector temp = temp_cross.cross_product(other);
            // Two vectors are parallel in 3D only if their cross product result is near zero.
            return temp[0] >= 0 && temp[0] <= 1E-6
                && temp[1] >= 0 && temp[1] <= 1E-6
                && temp[2] >= 0 && temp[2] <= 1E-6;
        }


        // Other dimensions: scalar product method. Parallelism condition if result's near 0 (approx 1E-6)
        template<typename T2>
        friend constexpr bool are_parallel(const vector& first, const vector<T2, Size>& other)
        requires (not is_complex<T>::value 
        and not is_complex<T2>::value) {
            auto sum_and_pow = [](auto sum, const auto& element) {
                return sum + std::pow(element, 2);
            };

            T inner_product = first.inner_product(other);
            double lhs = std::pow(inner_product, 2);
            double rhs1 = std::accumulate(std::begin(first._vector), std::end(first._vector),
                0, sum_and_pow);
            double rhs2 = std::accumulate(std::begin(other._vector), std::end(other._vector),
                0, sum_and_pow);
            return std::abs(rhs1 * rhs2 - lhs) <= 1E-6;
        }

        // Perpendicular conditions
        template<typename T2>
        friend constexpr bool are_perpendicular(const vector& first, const vector<T2, Size>& other)
        requires (not is_complex<T>::value 
        and not is_complex<T2>::value) {
            auto inner_product = first.inner_product(other);
            return inner_product >= 0 && inner_product <= 1E-6;
        }

        // Angle between two vectors (in radiants)
        // Todo: Add support for complex vectors
        template<typename T2>
        constexpr double angle_between_radiants(const vector<T2, Size>& other)
        requires (not is_complex<T>::value) {
            double inner_prod = inner_product(other);
            double magnitude_mult = magnitude() * other.magnitude();
            ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(magnitude_mult);

            return std::acos(inner_prod / magnitude_mult);
        }

        template<typename T2>
        constexpr double angle_between_degrees(const vector<T2, Size>& other) {
            return angle_between_radiants(other) * 180 / 3.141592653589793238463;
        }

        constexpr bool is_empty() const {
            return (Size == 0 || std::all_of(std::begin(_vector), std::end(_vector),
                [](value_type i) { return i == value_type{}; }));
        }

        auto operator<=>(const vector&) const = default;

        template<typename Stream>
        constexpr void print(Stream& stream) const {
            for (auto x : _vector) stream << x << ' ';
            stream << '\n';
        }

        consteval value_type size() const noexcept {
            return Size;
        }

        constexpr auto begin() const noexcept {
            return std::begin(_vector);
        }

        constexpr auto end() const noexcept {
            return std::end(_vector);
        }

        constexpr auto begin() noexcept {
            return std::begin(_vector);
        }

        constexpr auto end() noexcept {
            return std::end(_vector);
        }

    };



    // Not in place counterparts
    template<underlying_vector_type T, std::size_t Size, typename T2>
    constexpr auto lambda_multiplication(const vector<T, Size>& vec, T2 lambda) {
        using Type = decltype(std::declval<T>()* std::declval<T2>());
        vector<Type, Size> temp(vec);

        return temp.lambda_multiplicator(lambda);
    }


    template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
    constexpr vector<T, Size> normalize(const vector<T, Size>& other) {
        vector<T, Size> copy(other);
        copy.normalize();

        return copy;
    }


  
    // Deduction guides
    // [1] aggregate initialization
    template<typename T2, std::same_as<T2>...Args>
    vector(T2, Args...)->vector<T2, sizeof...(Args) + 1>;

    // [2] complex numbers deduction 
    template <arithmetic_char_const_excluded T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
    vector(T const (&arr)[N][M])->vector<std::complex<T>, N>;


}

#endif
```
````

Comment: The requirements in the `get_` methods look excessive because the code would not compile if `Size < 3`.  Maybe `requires (Size >= 3)` should be applied to the whole class.

Comment: The `subtraction` is misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Consistency

You mix `and` and `&&`, and `not` and `!`. Choose one and stay consistent.

## Namespace

Using a namespace is a good idea to avoid name clashes. That being said, giving the namespace a very common name, such as `Math` is likely to reintroduce the issue.

## unsigned integer

I spotted some parts in the code where you disable certain functions for unsigned integers or even marked them deprecated. Considering that unsigned integers, i.e. natural numbers, do not form a vector space in the first place, I'd rather prohibit the entire class from being constructed with them.

## preprocessor macros

I would define the macros outside the namespace, because they are not affected by it either way

## Naming conventions

Typically, class names are written with a capital letter `class Vector`

## Unnecessary restriction

`enum class Cos { ALPHA = 0, BETA, THETA };`

and

```
constexpr double direction_cosine(Cos type) const 
        requires (Size == 3 
        and not is_complex<T>::value) {
            double denominator = magnitude();
            ASSERT_DIV_BYZERO(denominator);

            return static_cast<double>(_vector[static_cast<int>(type)] / denominator);
        }
```

I'd consider naming the enum values `X_AXIS`, `Y_AXIS` and `Z_AXIS`, because you're somewhat mixing conventions here. But then again, this can be generalized to n-dimensions and you do not need an enum nor the three dimensional restriction.

## Mix of C with C++

`T _vector[Size]{};` is a C-style array. In C++ this should be

```
std::array<T, Size> _vector;
```

you need to `#include <array>` for it. You made a good habit of using stl algorithms, so you can just swap the declarations and your code still compiles.

## Constants

```
template<typename T2>
constexpr double angle_between_degrees(const vector<T2, Size>& other) {
    return angle_between_radiants(other) * 180 / 3.141592653589793238463;
}
```

Why do you not use `M_PI` which is defined in `<cmath>` that you even include? Also, while the constant is very well known, it should really be a constant. You can define it as a static member variable `conversion_rad2deg`.

## stream operator

I'm not sure if it makes sense to use a template here:

```
template<typename Stream>
constexpr void print(Stream& stream) const {
    for (auto x : _vector) stream << x << ' ';
    stream << '\n';
}
```

Also your version does not return the stream, so I can not chain it, as is usually possible. Instead I'd write:

```
constexpr std::ostream& print(std::ostream& stream) const {
    for (auto const& x : _vector) stream << x << ' ';
    stream << '\n';
    return stream;
}
```

## std::accumulate

You should check the performance on this one. Before C++20 it copied by value and didn't move. So it could be quite slow for bigger vectors. For smaller vectors it should be fine.

## Dangerous Bug

```
template<typename T2>
        friend constexpr bool are_perpendicular(const vector& first, const vector<T2, Size>& other)
        requires (not is_complex<T>::value 
        and not is_complex<T2>::value) {
            auto inner_product = first.inner_product(other);
            return inner_product >= 0 && inner_product <= 1E-6;
        }
```

This introduces a potentially dangerous bug. Comparing floating point numbers is hard. But hardcoding the `1E-6` is a very bad solution. Furthermore, the inner product can be negative. So you should at least check `std::abs`. The easiest fix would be to allow an epsilon parameter, that you compare against.

This code appears in several other places so you should really consider making it a function, i.e. `is_near_zero(double d)` or `is_approximately_equal(double x, double y)`.

## Problems

You mentioned that not everything is yet defined. For example, I can not add a vector of complex numbers to a vector of doubles.

## Comments

Overall this looks well done and a lot of good paradigms were followed. I wouldn't create a polar_vector class though. Simply supply a constructor that takes `r`, `theta` and `phi`. Once you implemented the `Matrix` class, you can also consider making the vector class a special case, i.e. `template<typename T, std::size_t n> using Row_Vector = Matrix<T, 1, n>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the review. I will fix all the issues now.
I have a question for the last comment: I can indeed supply a constructor that takes `r` and `theta` (and other angles if I implement spherical and cylindrical coordinates); but perhaps that would prevent me from treating the vector like an actual polar vector? How would you go and implement that for example?

Comment: you mean that you can add them radially or angularlly? No, that won't work.

Comment: So basically I could just implement the constructor for a polar vector (ie, a constructor taking `r` and `theta`) and just convert from that coordinate system to cartesian, so everything else would work normally?

Comment: @SomeonePassionate Yes, the internal representation would be cartesian.

Comment: Thank you, I like the idea.
Once again, thanks for the time in reviewing this. Really appreciated!